# smarty autoindent html

Tags: vim, smarty, auto-indent

Is there any plugin that I can use to auto indent html in "smarty" template.
the way i do this in vim is like:
while editing a smarty template:
`:set filetype=html`

press "=G" after moving cursor to the head of file
Is there a plugin for vim that can do this for me?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's still looking for an answer to this, simply add the following line to your vimrc:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.tpl set filetype=html
```

The above will treat .tpl files as HTML. You can swap the values (tpl/html) for whatever other combination as well.

Once your file is open, just use this keystroke to indent:

```
gg=G
```

Answer (score 1):

This plugin handles indenting of HTML and PHP in Smarty templates: https://github.com/blueyed/smarty.vim

Answer (score 0):

You weren't clear on what editor you were looking for a plugin for (vim?).

There are a number of IDE's that support Smarty formatting. I personally use [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) (see [Smarty plugin for NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551693/smarty-plugin-for-netbeans)), but there are also [PHP Storm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), [CodeLobster](http://www.codelobster.com/), and [Aptana](http://aptana.org/) to name a few more.

Comment: thank for the answer.Sorry for not describing it clear, the editor I use is VIM though.